# unable to send json data via ajax

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, ajax, json

I'm creating a json data with a click event. then i am trying to send the json data to my php script via ajax and alert a response. But i'm unable to send the json data to my php script. its returning NUll.

**jquery script:**

```
var jsonObj = [];
$("#additembtn").click(function(event){
event.preventDefault();
var obj = {};
obj["medicine_name"]=parsed.medicine_name;
obj["quantity"]=unit;
obj["price"]=price;
jsonObj.push(obj);
console.log(jsonObj);
})

$("#order").click(function(event){
event.preventDefault();
$jsonObj=JSON.stringify(jsonObj)
$.ajax({
url: "../siddiqa/function/ordermedicine.php",
type: "POST",
//dataType: "json",
data: jsonObj,
success:function(data, textStatus, jqXHR)
        {
        alert(data);

        },
error: function(jqXHR, textStatus, errorThrown)
        {
            //if fails   

        }
})


})
```

**PHP SCRIPT**

```
<?php
require_once('../configuration.php');
$con=new mysqli($hostname,$dbusername,$dbpass,$dbname);
if (mysqli_connect_errno($con)) {
    die('The connection to the database could not be established.');
}
$obj = json_decode($_POST['jsonObj']);

echo $obj['medicine_name'];


?>
```

Unable to get use data on php script and the php returning NULL reponse

Comment: whats the error? anything on console? network tab?

Comment: Unable to get use data on php script and the php returning NULL reponse

Comment: Do `print_r($_POST);` in your PHP script, that should show you the problem. You're trying to access `$_POST['jsonObj']`, when there is no jsonObj key in your post data.

Comment: print_r($_POST) returning Array
(
    [undefined] => 
)
@seventoes

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The problem is that you are trying to send an array and you need to send an `object`:

```
$.ajax({
  url: "../siddiqa/function/ordermedicine.php",
  type: "POST",
  data: { data: jsonObj },
  success:function(data, textStatus, jqXHR) { alert(data); },
  error: function(jqXHR, textStatus, errorThrown) { }
});
```

Then in your PHP side you could get the value writing: `$obj = $_POST['data'];`

Comment: Thanks a lot, Now Its returing the data. It returning the data as follows
Array
(
    [data] => Array
        (
            [0] => Array
                (
                    [medicine_name] => napa extra
                    [quantity] => 2
                    [price] => 22
                )

            [1] => Array
                (
                    [medicine_name] => minium 10
                    [quantity] => 2
                    [price] => 10
                )

        )

)

now how to get the medicine name from the array? 
echo $_POST['medicine_name']; not working

Comment: I am not familiar with PHP but you need to access the medicine_name through the $obj var... probably writing something like this $obj[0]['medicine_name']

Comment: $obj = json_decode($_POST['data']);
returing
Warning:  json_decode() expects parameter 1 to be string, array given in /home/windsys/public_html/siddiqa/function/ordermedicine.php on line 7

Comment: @oyshee as I said I am not familiar with PHP, probably the json_decode is not needed becuase your data is already a json so try with this: $obj = $_POST['data']

Comment: thanks a lot again. Can you please answer me another question? 
i want to know how much object is in the json data. i mean $obj[0], $obj[1]...
I'm trying to echo $obj.length; But not working. Will you please help me to echo the total object?

Comment: @oyshee I think you could do this: get_object_vars(&obj).length  http://php.net/manual/en/function.get-object-vars.php

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/66879/discussion-between-ianaya89-and-oyshee).

Answer (score 0):

JSON object should be an object, not array. You better do something like this.

```
$jsonObj = {array: jsonObj};
$jsonObj = JSON.stringify(jsonObj);
```